# Making unattainable demands on employees

Tags: management

We are a receiving crew that works well together and before the new changes we were getting the job done.  Now we have demands put on us with unreasonable time limits.

We are required to break down a pallet stacked with boxes (6 employees) in 5 minutes per pallet. Most of the boxes are taller than us. The work involves scanning boxes, cutting them open, emptying the boxes and breaking them down. The mixed items from the boxes also have to be sorted.

Then we are required to put out carts full of items and racks full of clothes in 8 minutes. These items are all over the store.  On top of this we are required to process bins of clothing that are waist high and large in 45 minutes.  This is 4 people opening, ticketing, sensoring, hanging and sizing.

The store manager, department managers or corporate people cannot do this, but tell us that if we do not do it then we can be terminated. Can they do this?

Comment: What country/state? Union, non-union?

Comment: Just a note - a lot of non-US countries have laws around "constructive dismissal" i.e. setting up employees to fail and then firing them for failing. It may be worth looking into what constructive dismissal laws your locale has.

Comment: @ArgumentBargument I agree with your comment that it sounds like this is what is happening. When I worked Retail a decade ago, this was a not so uncommon practice of my company. If a department manager wasn't impressing the Regional VP, targets would suddenly become impossibly difficult to hit and within a month or two a new manager would be in that person's place.

Comment: @ArgumentBargument the same applies for the US, even in "right to work" states.

Answer (score 13):

They can demand anything they want, but if it's not possible, it's not possible and it certainly sounds unreasonable because there is also the factor of moving the pallets and bins or the workers and removing the completed ones as well as the completed work.

I have worked in a factory (engineering) where two of us were expected to hang, powdercoat and bake a product at an unachievable rate. There was a bottleneck in the time needed to bake and it would have taken three men working hard on the line at different points anyway. We just did what we could and quality was affected from trying to rush.

We ended up telling the boss that it's just not possible and being an intelligent adult and watching us for a while he changed his requirements.

But if he hadn't, we'd have ended up quitting. There is no point in working for people who are not intelligent adults. So I wouldn't have waited to be terminated. These are not highly skilled jobs, it's fairly easy to find another.

In these sorts of jobs, your foreman or manager is at fault here, he/she should be showing you by example how this can be achieved, and if they can't do that, they should be the ones having a conversation with the bosses. You don't just tell workers on an assembly line to make something, you show them.

Comment: It might be worth while asking for training and/or a demonstration on how to do the job at the required rate.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan might be worth asking, but should already be given, it's the foreman/managers job to handle that. As a foreman it was one of my main roles. If the bosses wanted something that couldn't be done, I'd tell them, I'm the experienced man on the ground, I'm supposed to know. This sounds like the bosses just being jerks for unknown reasons.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan My father in his job did that to a supervisor, who immediately backed off.  I've used the same tactic myself.  It works very well to distinguish between the intelligent adults and the lunatics.